# Solving $\int_1^2 e^{1-\frac{1}{(x-1)^2}} + 2 + \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-\log(x-1)}}\:dx$ with a clean trick

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

A friend and I have been swapping difficult integrals for the holidays  to stump each other and he recently sent me this one that I haven't been able to figure out (mission accomplished, I guess :) ).

I've tried a few substitutions of the form

$$x-1 = f(t)$$

but if they cancel out one side, they won't simplify on the other because of the presence of both the exponential and the log. At best I could simplify the problem to

$$2 + \int_0^1 e^{1-\frac{1}{x^2}} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-\log x}}\:dx$$

by shifting the integral over to the interval $[0,1]$ to see if I could spot any patterns. The integral on the right [evaluates to $1$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Integrate%5BExp%5B1-%281%2Fx%5E2%29%5D+%2B++1%2FSqrt%5B1-Log%5Bx%5D%5D%2C%7Bx%2C0%2C1%7D%5D+), which is a surprisingly clean answer.

Wolfram gives a [complicated looking antiderivative](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Integrate%5BExp%5B1-%281%2F%28x-1%29%5E2%29%5D+%2B+2+%2B+1%2FSqrt%5B1-Log%5Bx-1%5D%5D%2Cx%5D+) but one of the rules of our little game was that we would invoke no special functions beyond the standard transcendentals and hyperbolics/trig. Even if this was the intended solution, I'm not sure how to simplify the bound at $1$ with the $\operatorname{erf}$s

I suspect he had some clean trick in mind since that was the theme of the game, but I'm stumped.

Comment: See [Integral of inverse functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_of_inverse_functions)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Hint:** Observe you have
\begin{align}
I=\int^2_1 e^{1-\frac{1}{(x-1)^2}}+1 +1+\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-\log(x-1)}}\ dx = \int^2_1 [f(x)+f^{-1}(x)]\ dx = 3.
\end{align}
Draw a picture (for any $f$)!

Comment: Wow that was beautiful! And I feel silly for not spotting that since my friend told me about that trick recently. Cheers!

Comment: As an edit though, this trick only works if the functions have fixed points at the end points of the integrals.